# how to call multiple ssh connection and run command through paramiko and store output of them in array format

Tags: python, paramiko

I use paramiko to create an ssh connection. I want to create multiple connections and run one command. Below is my code

```
for i in ii:
# print(i)
mylist = []
try:
    client.connect(hostname=i[0], port='22', username='root', password='sidra123')
    # print(i)
    grepCommand = "protoc --version"
    output = ''
    stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command(grepCommand)
    for line in stdout:
        output = output + line
        # print(output)
        mylist.append(output)
        client.close()
finally:
    print(mylist)

   return 'data'
```

I having error at append - only last result will be appended to the list. How to solve this problem?

Comment: you should create `mylist = []` before `for i in ii:`. Now you create new `mylist` in every loop so you delete previous result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create `mylist` before loop.

```
mylist = []
for i in ii:
    # print(i)
    # ... rest ...
```

Currently you create new mylist in every loop so you delete its previous content.